$F$ is bounded in $\overline{H}_a$ and it is analytic in the interior of $\overline{H}_a$
Let $\mathbb{R}^+_0 = [0, \infty)$. The Laplace transform of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^+_0 \to \mathbb{C}$, for $p = \sigma + i\tau$ with $\sigma$ and $\tau$ real, is defined as:
$$
F(p) = (\mathcal{L}f)(p) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt} \, dt,
$$
provided the integral exists. For $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we say that $f \in E_a$ if:
$$
\int_0^\infty |f(t)|e^{-at} \, dt < +\infty.
$$
I have proved that for $f \in E_a$, the Laplace integral is absolutely convergent and that the Laplace integral is also uniformly convergent in $\overline{H}_a = \{ p \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re}(p) \geq a \}$.
Now, I have a suspicion that $F$ is bounded in $\overline{H}_a$ and it is analytic in the interior of $\overline{H}_a$.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Concerning boundedness in $\overline{H}_a$, let $p \in \overline{H}_a$:
\begin{align}\label{eq} \int_0^\infty \lvert f(t) e^{-pt} \rvert dt = \int_0^\infty \lvert f(t) \rvert e^{-Re(p)t} dt \leq \int_0^\infty \lvert f(t) \rvert e^{-at}dt < \infty.
\end{align}
The expression on the right-hand side is a uniform bound (independent of $p$) for $F$ in $\overline{H}_a$, i.e. $F$ is bounded in $\overline{H}_a$.
Concerning analyticity in the interior of $\overline{H}_a$, by Morera's theorem it suffices to show that $F$ is continuous and the integral of $F$ over any triangle vanishes. Continuity follows immediately using dominated convergence and the uniform estimate above. So let $\Delta \subset \overline{H}_a$ a triangle:
$$ \int_\Delta F(p) dp = \int_\Delta \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-pt} dt dp = \int_0^\infty f(t) \int_\Delta e^{-pt} dp dt = 0, $$
where we used in the last equality that $\int_\Delta e^{-pt} dp = 0$ for any $t \in (0,\infty)$ because of Goursat's integral lemma. Exchanging the two integrals is justified by Fubini because the integrals converge absolutely due to the first argument proving boundedness.
